# btrfs device add: different mount options than for seed?

Tags: btrfs

I have a btrfs seed device, created with mixed data+metadata (`mkfs.btrfs --mixed`), and also `--metadata single`. This device is read-only. When doing `btrfs device add /dev/sdc1 /mnt`, is it possible to disable mixed-mode and to change the metadata profile for this second device? Or do creation options apply to all devices?

Comment: @mikeserv I've learned a lot from your pointers and am experimenting with btrfs

Comment: Looks like you can w/ [`btrfs-balance`](https://btrfs.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Manpage/btrfs-balance) - though i dunno about getting out --mixed mode. For the *profiles* its talking about, see `man mkfs.btrfs`.

Comment: But but but!!! If the first mounted device is read-only (as is the case for seeds) btrfs-balance immediately exits with an error.

Comment: I don't think so - the rebalance will be necessary. Unless it might be worked into send/receive or something. I dunno. You're going over my head man - it's been awhile since i got into the fs nitty-gritty.

Comment: You gotta umount it first. You can't balance a readonly. Remember you asked why umount the seed? It was because i needed the dev to be replaced so i could remount rw. Once the loop was associated with the array it remained attach to the seed - but umounting then mounting the ram disk enabled the dev to come up rw.

Answer (score 0):

`man btrfs device` reports:

> Profile names, used in profiles and convert are one of: raid0, raid1, raid10, raid5, raid6, dup, single. The mixed data/metadata profiles can be converted in the same way, but it’s conversion between mixed and non-mixed is not implemented.

So according to this, you would be unable to change out of `mixed` mode, though you could change from `single` to `dup` (anything else would need more than one writable device).